Why does Firebase Crashlytics fail to build when Android gradle configuration cache is turned on?
I've recently added Firebase Crashlytics to my Android game app and don't understand why it fails to build unless I turn off configuration cache. I'm using gradle v8.7 and AGP v8.4.1. I'm building on the command line in Windows like this:
gradlew --no-configuration-cache app:assembleDevelopmentDebug app:uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileDevelopmentDebug

If I remove the "--no-configuration-cache" parameter it fails as follows.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Configuration cache problems found in this build.

1 problem was found storing the configuration cache.
- Task `:app:generateCrashlyticsSymbolFileDevelopmentDebug` of type `com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.gradle.tasks.GenerateSymbolFileTask`: invocation of 'Task.project' at execution time is unsupported.

> Invocation of 'Task.project' by task ':app:generateCrashlyticsSymbolFileDevelopmentDebug' at execution time is unsupported.

This is my gradle.properties file:
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
android.useAndroidX=true
kotlin.code.style=official
android.prefabVersion=2.0.0
android.injected.testOnly=false
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx8092M -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options\="-Xmx8092M"
android.nonTransitiveRClass=false
android.nonFinalResIds=false
org.gradle.configuration-cache=true

